# Get ID from array and put it on another array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my code

```
function ...($id){
   $data = array(
   'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'id' => $id
    );

    $data2 = array( 
    'inv_id' = $data['id']
    );
}
```

I couldn't get the value of the id from the first array(`$data`).

Is it possible to get the value of the key `id` from the first array(`$data`) to the second array

Answer (score 2):

while assigning array elements you must use '=>' operator'
like below: -

`$data2 = array( 
'inv_id' => $data['id']
);`

Answer (score 1):

```php
function ...($id){
   //changes in the line below.
   $inp_arr = ['name' => $this->input->post('name'),'id' => $id];

    $some_other_arr = array( 
    'inv_id' = $inp_arr['id']
    );
}
```

## Edit 1:

```php
//it is => 
'inv_id' => $inp_arr['id'] //pointed out in one of the answer.
```

Comment: still could not get the same ID saved on the first array

Comment: just try the following code to see, if the value is being initialized.

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($inp_arr); die();`

Comment: can you please post the output? What does it look like?

Comment: ohhh my id is always 0 because i let my database be an auto increment . this is a problem >.<

Comment: It did not solve the answer but you give me a hint . Thank you

Comment: @dexter where does it say in the documentation as `$data is reserved by framework(codeigniter)` ??

Answer (score 1):

Please use separator '=>' for the associative arrays.

Example:

```
$data2 = array(
         'inv_id' => $data['id']
         );
```